# Can we say '... put me up with it'

Tags: word-usage

My friend and I were talking about the cold weather in my city, and she said 'flowers and blossoming trees put me up with it'. I know 'put up with' means 'endure without resentment',e.g. They put up with the bad weather. However, can we say 'The bad weather put me up with it'? I didn't find such usage in Longman or OED.

Comment: I've never heard this usage.

Comment: The flowers _helped her to put up with_ the cold weather.